# Set Colorbar color in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate, special
import pylab
def f(v,r):
    """ Initial function"""
    alpha = 0.2
    chi = 1/2*special.erf((r+1.2)/0.3)-1/2*special.erf((r-1.2)/0.3)
    return 4/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi*alpha))*chi*np.exp(-v**2/(2*alpha))


N_xi = 100

v = (np.arange(N_xi)*4/(N_xi - 1)-2)
r = (np.arange(N_xi)*4/(N_xi - 1)-2)
z = f(v.reshape(-1, 1), r.reshape(1, -1))

pylab.pcolor(v, r, z)

pylab.colorbar()

pylab.show()
```

And I got the figure:[image]
But I want to change the color of it, to get the figure like this[image]
How can I set the color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the `jet` [colormap](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap) when creating the [`pcolor`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor) object

```
pylab.pcolor(v, r, z, cmap='jet')
```

That being said, the `jet` colormap isn't ideal for many situations so take care to [choose an appropriate colormap](http://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html).

[image]